# Pokemon Ultra Sun game restarts every time the game is played

Tags: pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon

For Christmas 2018 my son got a 3DSXL & Pokémon Ultra Sun (Digital estore) game. He’s played it a few times, but it seems like every time he reopens it he starts from the very beginning. Can someone guide me & let me know how to continue the previously saved game on Pokémon Ultra Sun?

Answer (score 5):

He has to manually save the game before closing it.
When starting the game up, the only option is to continue from last save, so you have to make sure your son is saving the game before quitting.

Answer (score 3):

**He needs to save the game.**

To save the game, first he needs to open the menu with the X button, then press the Y button or press it directly from the touch screen to save the game.

I add an image of the menu and where you can see the save option.

[image: USUM]

[Link to the original image](https://nintendosoup.com/game-review-pokemon-ultra-sun-ultra-moon/)